# Error running Payara Server from IntelliJ with error "ERROR: Error parsing system bundle statement."

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, payara

I'm brand new to JPA and JDBC and still learning about it. I'm trying to run a simple JPA program from IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, using Payara Server 5.2021.4, and connecting to and Apache Derby Database.

The first thing I'm trying to troubleshoot right now is that the Payara Server doesn't deploy, and then I'll try to figure if the DB connection is working correctly.

Here is the console when I include the --verbose flag in the running configuration:

```
  C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain --verbose domain1
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\MarkReinke\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath518436922 com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 55738 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish51Agent
[2021-07-28 01:24:41,381] Artifact jpa:war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Jul 28, 2021 1:24:41 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe
-cp
C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jrt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.logging/java.util.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-server
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.security.policy=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER=org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Djdbc.drivers=org.h2.Driver
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.force-selector-spin-detection=true
-Djava.library.path=C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_281/bin;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;C:/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.10/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Python39/Scripts;C:/Python39;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH;C:/Program Files/Git/cmd;C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin;C:/kompose-windows-amd64.exe;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools;C:/Program Files/nodejs;C:/Program Files/CMake/bin;C:/Users/MarkReinke/Documents/Program Files/ffmpeg-4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build/bin;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/bundle-tool;C:/Program Files (x86)/Box/Box Edit;C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin;C:/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin;C:/db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin/bin;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2/bin;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Roaming/npm;C:/Users/MarkReinke/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin;C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/bin
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-upgrade
false
-domaindir
C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--extraterse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,--autoname=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=true,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\payara-5.2021.4\payara5\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-domainname
domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
true
-asadmin-classpath
C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain
-watchdog
false
Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle statement.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:865)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:217)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerRevision.update(ExtensionManager.java:982)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerRevision.access$000(ExtensionManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.updateRevision(ExtensionManager.java:378)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:748)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:93)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlers (file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/osgi/felix/bin/felix.jar) to constructor sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlers
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Jul 28, 2021 1:24:42 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [161](R 161.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [161](R 161.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113](R 113.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113](R 113.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.core.glassfish [113](R 113.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.utils [138](R 138.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.utils [138](R 138.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [161](R 161.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [161](R 161.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [133](R 133.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [133](R 133.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management) Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config [133](R 133.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1539)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/osgi-resource-locator.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator [1](R 1.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-analysis.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis [19](R 19.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))])
ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.commons [20] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-commons.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.commons [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.tree [21] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-tree.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.tree [21](R 21.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))])
ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm.util [22] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm-util.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm.util [22](R 22.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.3.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle org.objectweb.asm [23] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/asm.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0)) Unresolved requirements: [[org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))])
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/class-model.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0): missing requirement [org.objectweb.asm [23](R 23.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5.0))] Unresolved requirements: [[org.glassfish.hk2.class-model [29](R 29.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.objectweb.asm.signature)(version>=7.1.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))])
ERROR: Bundle fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46] Error starting file:/C:/payara-5.2021.4/payara5/glassfish/modules/config-types.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0): missing requirement [fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0): missing requirement [org.glassfish.hk2.api [132](R 132.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [161](R 161.0): missing requirement 

[org.glassfish.hk2.external.jakarta.inject [161](R 161.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]] Unresolved requirements: [[fish.payara.server.internal.hk2.config-types [46](R 46.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))])


=======
More errors, but Stack Overflow character limit
===============
    
    
        Error 

stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.shutdown()" because the return value of "com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.access$000(com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher)" is null
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.shutdown()" because the return value of "com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.access$000(com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher)" is null
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(GlassFishMain.java:222)
    Command start-domain failed.
    The DAS was stopped.
```

Here is a picture of the project structure:
[Project Structure Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05TtY.png)   [Project Structure Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6eBc.png)

Here is my pom.xml:
[pom.xml part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIVqz.png)  [pom.xml part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y3CP.png)  [pom.xml part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGTGy.png)

And here is my run configuration:
[Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y88j0.png)

Please let me know if I need to submit more information to troubleshoot! Thank you